# Can I adjust metrics on my two network interfaces?

Tags: 14.04, networking, routing

I have two subnets.

192.168.6.x for special purposes, and I am cabled directly to the router by Ethernet.  It has an WAN connection to the internet gateway so the specialized devices can do software updates, but they primarily talk to each other.  Each has a static address and a hosts file so they are all accessible by name.

The service entrance is 192.168.1.1 and I can directly to it via WiFi with a static IP address.

> On Windows 7 and 8.1 it is very easy to set the .1 interface to have a
>   metric of 1 and the .6 have a metric of 10.
>
> > Any time I need to communicate with a unit on .6 there is only one
> >     interface that can do it, so all is fine.
> >
> > When I need to do an Internet stream or download it favors the .1
> >     interface and doesn't interfere with the instrumentation.

So now, with a new ubuntu 14.04 machine becoming such a useful workstation I need the same setup for it.

.6 is cabled to Ethernet, and .1 is via WiFi.  Right now it seems very random which path a large download will take, often upsetting the data loggers on .6

---

**Network configuration is done in the GUI Setup, Network screen.**

**eth0 is 192.168.6.204, gateway 192.168.6.1, dns 192.168.1.1**

**wlan1 is 192.168.1.214, gateway 192.168.1.1, dns 192.168.1.1**

and

**/etc/interfaces looks like this:**

[image]

**There is no /wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicants file.**

**/etc/hosts looks like this:**

[image]

**The route command returns this:**

[image]

**Which shows the metrics exactly the opposite of what I want, and even though the gateway address for wlan1 shows as 192.168.1.1 in the setup screen it doesn't show it in the routing table.**

So clearly I have two problems in the routing table.  Metrics and gateways.

My original question is in the title:  Can I adjust metrics on my two network interfaces?  But the more I look into this I think I should change the title to ask how do you control ubuntu 14.04 networking other than by the GUI.

Comment: Witch net will need be with less metric, eth or wifi?

Comment: Eth will need a higher metric number.  It is connected directly to the PiNet router that coordinates all the sensors and data logging, and it is the only route that can access them.  But both can get to the internet, so I want WiFi to have a lower metric number so it is preferred for everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `metric` to your interface

If you use `dhcp` to configure `eth` interface

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interface
```

then add metric

```
auto eth0
  iface eth2 inet dhcp
  metric 800
```

If you have static ip

```
auto eth1
  iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.10.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.10.0.1
    metric 800
```

Also you can create script to change `gefault gateway`

Example:

```
 sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/script
```

and put content

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "eth0" ] || exit 0
# put default gw to wless 
route add default dev wlan0
```

give script privilege

```
chmod 755 /etc/network/if-up.d/script
```

`if-up.d` will trigger script called script when `eth0` go up and put default gw to `wlan0`

Or you can to manually add `metric` to route

```
sudo route add default gw 10.10.0.1 metric 800
```

10.10.10.1 is default gateway for eth network

Or if you do not need resources on ethernet subnet except that subnet,
I mean all the host you talk trough cable is on same subnet, you can delete default gw from eth card setting.

Comment: Everything you show here looks like it would would work on a Raspberry Pi.    So I just updated the question to show the state of the system under ubuntu 14.04 - it is a different animal.

Comment: Try to change route and default gateway with command 'sudo route add default dev wlan1'